How to share nested nav graph screen viewmodel to parent nav graph screen
I'm working with Jetpack Compose and Hilt for dependency injection in a nested navigation setup. I need to share a ViewModel (specifically, nested_home ViewModel) between a nested screen (NestedHomeScreen) and its parent screen (HomeScreen). Both screens are part of different navigation graphs, but I want the HomeScreen to be able to access the same ViewModel instance used in NestedHomeScreen.
@Composable
fun MainNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
        composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController) }
        composable("profile") { ProfileScreen(navController) }
        composable("nested_container") { NestedContainerScreen(navController) }
    }
}


@Composable
fun NestedContainerScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    // Create a nested NavController for the subgraph
    val nestedNavController = rememberNavController()

    // Nested NavHost as the subgraph
    NavHost(navController = nestedNavController, startDestination = "nested_home") {
        composable("nested_home") {
            NestedHomeScreen(nestedNavController)
        }
        composable("nested_detail/{id}") { backStackEntry ->
            val id = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("id")
            NestedDetailScreen(id = id)
        }
    }
}


val nestedHomeViewModel : HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()

//need to access it in parent nav host home screen


Note:

Do not use global scope viewmodel to parent navhost to share
Do not use subgraph using navigation


NavBackStackEntry is also a ViewModelStoreOwner that stores ViewModels and return same ViewModels for same ViewModel classes by using them as String keys. ViewModels are stored in ViewModelStore with
private val map = mutableMapOf<String, ViewModel>()

If you scope your ViewModel with a parent NavBackStackEntry you can access it from multiple graphs or navigations.
val parentBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry = navController.getBackStackEntry("home")

val nestedHomeViewModel : HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentBackStackEntry)

As you can see hiltViewModel takes a LocalViewModelStoreOwner which is from current destination via LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current
@Composable
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> hiltViewModel(
    viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    },
    key: String? = null
): VM {
    val factory = createHiltViewModelFactory(viewModelStoreOwner)
    return viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner, key, factory = factory)
}

Also be advised that getBackStackEntry is not found it throws exception because of that you might use try-catch, store a constant or use type-safe navigation to make sure that you access parent NavBackStackEntry.

It works, but when I use typesafety nav arguments to inject savedstatehandle in viewmodel it gets null. When using savedstatehandle.toRoute<> in hiltviewmodel, it is not giving the values in nested_home args.

I will check this out. Scoping works with both so should passing arguments via route and getting them from SavedStateHandle because NavBackStackEntry also implements SavedStateRegistryOwner and passes same SavedStateRegistryto ViewModels. And in this case it's also same ViewModel.  Would you mind asking this as another question?

In this link i created a shared ViewModel between screen and dialog as well. I will also check if savedStaetHandles work or not but it would be nice to see how you implement it.
